# Properties.Settings does not save list view items

Tags: c#

Hey Im working on a software solution and I have a listview in my program and would like to save it.

```
var listview = new List<string>();
    foreach (ListViewItem Item in listView1.Items)
    {
       listview.Add(Item.Text.ToString());
    }
StringCollection collection = new StringCollection();
Properties.Settings.Default.ListViewItems = collection;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Im tryring to save it with settings but when i try to call it the value is null

[image: here is my list]

But when i try to load my table i cant do it like so.
When i'm trying to call my table it isnt working like this.

```
var collection = Properties.Settings.Default.ListViewItems;
    if (collection != null)
    {
        List<string> list = collection.Cast<string>().ToList();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("null");
    }
```

Comment: `StringCollection collection = new StringCollection();` - this creates an empty collection - and then you're **overwriting** `ListViewItems` with this empty collection and then saving.

Comment: Unrelated: `ListViewItem.Text` is already a `String` value - you don't need to call `.ToString()`.

Comment: so i need to delete StringCollection collection = new StringCollection(); ?

Comment: Unrelated: A "ListView" is a UI control (present in WinForms, WPF, etc) - or it can represent a _view_ of an existing list - but you're naming a `List<String>` as "listView" which is misleading.

Comment: @Dai so can you give me a solution for my problem? :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have items in `listView1.Items` and you want to save them to the WinForms `Settings` system.

Do it like so:

```
var settings = Properties.Settings.Default;
if( settings.ListViewItems is null ) settings.ListViewItems = new StringCollection();
foreach( ListViewItem lvi in listView1.Items )
{
    settings.ListViewItems.Add( lvi.Text );
}
settings.Save();
```

---

Annoyingly, the `StringCollection` type has a method named `AddRange` but it only accepts `String[]` and not `IEnumerable<String>` - and .NET doesn't come with a stock `AddRange` method for the non-generic `IList`. So I recommend you avoid using the `Settings` system because it's weakly-typed and doesn't play-nice with the modern C# ecosystem, like support for Linq.

Comment: okay verry much thank you this helped me a lot when i want to load the list can i do it like?

Comment: one probmlem i still have wehn i save it it only saves the text and not the data i thin it is because the lvi.text how to i change it